# Android Button click is working only once

Tags: android, android-intent

I made a registration form which consists of a set of text fields and a register button. When the register button is clicked, it checks for any empty text fields and if exists, it returns 0 and starts the activity again. But the problem is the button click event is working only once. The next time when the button is clicked, the application is closing.

Here is the code,

```
    public class Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener { 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        Button btnRegister=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegisterMe);

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(Register.this);


    }

@Override

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.btnRegisterMe)
        {
            int controlsCheck=CheckForEmptyTextBox();
            if(controlsCheck==0)
            {
                Toast toastSome=Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Check the             error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toastSome.show();


            }

        }

    }

        protected int CheckForEmptyTextBox()
    {
        int check;
        EditText txtMobile=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMobile);
        EditText txtUsername=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
        EditText txtPassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);



        if(txtMobile.length()==0)
        {
            txtMobile.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            Toast toastMobile=Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Enter Mobile Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toastMobile.show();

            check=0;

        }

        else if(txtUsername.length()==0)
        {
            txtUsername.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            Toast toastUsername=Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Enter Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toastUsername.show();

            check=0;

        }

        else if(txtPassword.length()==0)
        {
            txtPassword.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            Toast toastPassword=Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toastPassword.show();
            check=0;

        }

                else
        {
            check=1;
        }

        if(check==0)
        {

            return check;
        }
        else

        {
            return check;
        }

    }

}
```

**I want to assure the user that he fills all the fields**. Kindly tell me how to handle the multiple click events of the same button in android.

Log data::

```
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at com.example.restaurants.Register.CheckForEmptyTextBox(Register.java:74)
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at com.example.restaurants.Register.onClick(Register.java:37)
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-29 18:16:51.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-29 18:23:27.667: D/TextLayoutCache(5704): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
06-29 18:23:27.737: D/libEGL(5704): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
06-29 18:23:27.797: D/libEGL(5704): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
06-29 18:23:27.867: D/libEGL(5704): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
06-29 18:23:27.877: D/libEGL(5704): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
06-29 18:23:28.117: D/OpenGLRenderer(5704): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: Kindly see the log data..This error is occuring when I click the register button second time.

Comment: It has username edittext field.

Comment: else if(txtUsername.length()==0)

Comment: not sure about the exact problem. you can try one thing.. instead of using findviewbyid every time inflate the edittexts in oncreate and declare them as member variable

Answer (score 0):

There is a null pointer exception at line no 74 in `Register.java` . First fix that. Possibly due to this exception `CheckForEmptyTextBox()` might be returning non-zero value.